# Update datasource and reload data on UITableView not reflecting updated datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

This is my piece of code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary oldDict = (NSDictionary )[dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"Don" forKey:@"Name"];
[dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
[self.tblview reloadData];
```

I have to reload my tableview.But the tableview is not reloaded.How to rectify it.

Comment: show your `cellForRow`

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{if(tableView == self.tblviewProject)
{self.tblviewProject.hidden = YES;
NSString *pname = [[self.projectArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"name"];
NSMutableDictionary *newDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *rowchange = (NSDictionary *) [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue]];
[newDic addEntriesFromDictionary:rowchange];
[newDic setObject:pname forKey:project];
[self.tblview beginUpdates];

Comment: [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue] withObject:newDic];
[self.tblview reloadData];
[self.tblview endUpdates];
}}

Comment: this is my cell for row...now i add begin and endupdates but it oesn't work.

Comment: Are you doing it in mainthread?

Comment: @RBH Don't put your code in comments. Put your code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to begin and end updates since you don't actually change your source array.

Instead of `[self.tblview reloadData]` call:

```
[self.tblview beginUpdates];
[self.tblview endUpdates];
```

Or, reload section also should work in this case.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {if(tableView == self.tblviewProject) {self.tblviewProject.hidden = YES; NSString *pname = [[self.projectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]; NSMutableDictionary *newDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; NSDictionary *rowchange = (NSDictionary *) [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue]]; [newDic addEntriesFromDictionary:rowchange]; [newDic setObject:pname forKey:project]; [self.tblview beginUpdates];

Comment: [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue] withObject:newDic]; [self.tblview reloadData]; [self.tblview endUpdates]; }}   But now it doesn't works for me...